# buscando dado no arquivo csv com Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

estou pesquisando uma solução pra um problema e não encontrei nada que conseguisse entender, até o momento,

tenho um arquivo csv que contém os dados nesse formato:

*0111-3/01,"Cultivo de arroz"*

À esquerda fica o código, e a direita a descrição, separados por vírgula.

**O arquivo possui mais de 2 mil linhas.**

O que preciso:

O usuário digita o código no campo html, então a função busca no arquivo.csv esse código, e retorna a descrição. Seria algo do tipo:

```
$("#idInputCódigo").focusout(function(){

    //abre arquivo csv que está junto com os arquivos do sistema na pasta _CSV

    arquivo = open(_CSV/arquivo.csv); //função inventada

    for( i = 0; i<quantidade de linhas; i++ ){

        //alguma forma de percorrer o arquivo até encontrar o código correspondente e retornar a descrição
    }
```

não sei se existe alguma biblioteca no javascript que facilita isso, enfim, toda ajuda é bem vinda.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, vou deixar a solução aqui para ajudar alguém um dia.

Eu converti meu arquivo csv em um arquivo json, tem vários sites na net que faz isso de forma automática, ficou assim:

json:

```
[
  {
    "code": "0111-3/01",
    "description": "Cultivo de arroz"
  },
  {
    "code": "0111-3/02",
    "description": "Cultivo de milho"
  },
  {
    "code": "0111-3/03",
    "description": "Cultivo de trigo"
  }, .... (mais de 2 mil itens)
    ]
```

criei uma variável no javascript contendo o json

```
var cnae = [
             {
              "code": "0111-3/01",
              "description": "Cultivo de arroz"
             }, 
               ....
```

depois criei a função javascript que busca o code na variável, e retorna a description

```
function CNAE(value){

   var descricao;
   for (var i = 0; i < cnae.length; i++){
      if (cnae[i].code == value){
        descricao = cnae[i].description;
        //aqui acho que o return pode ser direto, sem a variável
        return descricao;
      }
   }

}
```

Apesar da quantidade de objetos na variável, funciona de forma instantânea, bem rápido.
Espero ajudar alguém.